# Embed XAML file's contents in another XAML file

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, uwp, uwp-xaml

I figured that this is pretty basic, but I need to take elements from elements.xaml and put it in Template.xaml as a child of the main grid "MainGrid". This can be done with either c# or XAML, it doesn't really matter.

Here is elements.xaml:

```
<TextBox Text='' FontSize='25' Grid.Column='0' Grid.Row='1'/>
<TextBox Text='' FontSize='25' Grid.Column='1' Grid.Row='1'/>
<TextBox Text='' FontSize='25' Grid.Column='2' Grid.Row='1'/>
<TextBox Text='' FontSize='25' Grid.Column='3' Grid.Row='1'/>
```

Here is Template.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="20" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAltMediumLowAcrylicElementMediumBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        //Defs go here
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        //Defs go here
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Head00" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Scene" FontSize="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Head10" Text="Characters" FontSize="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Head20" Text="Page" FontSize="50" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Head30" Text="Mic Assignment Number" FontSize="50" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

I want the embedded XAML to go under the Textblocks. Can you guys help?

EDIT: elements.xaml is in the applicationdata folder, at C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PACKAGENAME\LocalState

Thanks,
Rajan

Comment: You can move it to custom `UserControl`

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: You can should create new item -> choose `User Control` -> tap `Add`. After that move your content to control's body. After that put your new control to page's body

Comment: OK, I get that part, but then I would have to change the location of elements.XAML, and I can't do that. Also, elements.xaml must stay the way it is in the code snippet in my question. But thatnks for the effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `XamlReader`, it can load XAML string content, and convert the string to the corresponding XAML element.

Here is a simple example:

```
        string defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
        string xaml = "<TextBlock xmlns=\"" + defaultNamespace + "\">Hello, world!</TextBlock>";
        // xaml content will be:
        // <TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">Hello, world!</TextBlock>
        var textBlock = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as TextBlock;
        this.rootGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

This example will bring a TextBlock to UI.

For more info about `XamlReader`, you can visit [XamlReader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader).